# jquery.forms + colorbox + dataTable

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatable, colorbox

Good day thanks for any answer.

I'm not a expert here, I was asking google a lot, but here I really don't know what to do...

I'm working with colorbox, jquery.forms and jquery.dataTable plugins at the same time on a table.

Here I have two forms, one for creating users and one for editing.
such as creating users link is off the table the script works perfectly fine.
the problem is with editing users, the links that are in the table, this content comes from ajax, colorbox works partially, achieved it then appears in colorbox window, but any script within , in the "onComplete" function is no longer working.
I don't have a clue what to do from here, I don't fine many backups for this integration, some articles or questions marks only using {frame:true} for colorbox and dataTable.

here is the code of the functions:

this is the NOT working area

```
function cargarColorbox(){
    $('.edit').colorbox({
        OnComplete:function(){ //this is not workin
            var formulario = $('#usuarios_edit');
            var options = {success: mostrarRespuesta2};
            $("#update_info").text('llegan js');
            formulario.ajaxForm(options);
            //Implementamos los listeners del formulario            
            function mostrarRespuesta2(responseText){
                $("#update_info").removeClass();
                $("#update_info").html(responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}


function initTable ()
    {
        return $('#DataTable').dataTable( {
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bProcessing": false,
        "sAjaxSource": 'usuarios/listado',
        "fnInitComplete": function(){
             cargarColorbox();
        },
  } );
}


function RefreshTable(tableId, urlData)
    {

      $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
      {
        table = $(tableId).dataTable();
        oSettings = table.fnSettings();

        table.fnClearTable(this);

        for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
        {
          table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
        }

        oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
        table.fnDraw();
      });
    }
```

this is the working area

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    initTable();
    $('#add').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('#add').colorbox({onComplete:function(){
            //recogemos las variables que necesitaremos
            var formulario = $('#usuarios_add'); 
            var pass1 = $('#usuarios_pass');
            var pass2 = $('#usuarios_pass2');
            var email = $('#usuarios_email');
            var confirmacion = "coinciden";
            var longitud = "La contraseña debe estar formada entre 6-15 carácteres (ambos inclusive)";
            var negacion = "No coinciden las contraseñas";
            var vacio = "La contraseña no puede estar vacía";
            var options = {success: mostrarRespuesta};

            formulario.ajaxForm(options);

            pass2.keyup(function(){
                coincidePassword();
            });

            email.focusout(function(){
                validar_email();
            });

                function mostrarRespuesta(responseText){
                    $("#update_info").removeClass();
                    $("#update_info").html(responseText);
                }

                function coincidePassword(){
                    var val1 = pass1.val();
                    var val2 = pass2.val();

                    if(val1 != val2){
                        $('#update_info').text(negacion).addClass('bad');
                    }

                    if(val1.length==0 || val2==""){
                        $('#update_info').text(vacio).addClass('bad');
                    }

                    if(val1.length<6 || val2.length>15){
                        $('#update_info').text(longitud).addClass('bad');
                    }

                    if(val1.length!=0 && val1==val2){
                        $('#update_info').text(confirmacion).removeClass('bad').addClass('good');
                    }
                }

                function validar_email()
                {
                    valor = email.val();

                    var filter = /[\w-\.]{3,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;

                    if(filter.test(valor)){
                        $('#update_info').text('El formato del E-mail es correcto').removeClass('bad').addClass('good');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#update_info').text('Ese no es un formato de E-mail').addClass('bad');

                    }
                }

        }, onClosed:function(){
            RefreshTable(table, 'usuarios/listado');
            initTable();
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Change `OnComplete` to `onComplete`.

Comment: good god, thank.. I can't believe it was just something like that -.-

Comment: I'll add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`OnComplete` is different than `onComplete`.
You should fix this to `onComplete`.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo Lohmann, at the end i have to modify the script, but is fully functional and maybe need to be Polish but if somebody need a example of integration here is it... http://pastebin.com/wcSxG9ac